# I'm not sure what this java row does

Tags: java

I should probably know that but I'm not sure what this line of code is doing:

```
int iEnd=i==grid.length - 1 ? 0:1;
```

Comment: debug it, maybe

Comment: Which bit don't you understand?  The `=`, the `==` or the `?` and `:` ?

Comment: It is the [ternary operator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm sorry that I reply tha late but I had a lot of trouble with my internet collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will set iEnd to 0 if i equals grind.length -1 otherwise it will set iEnd to 1

the operator is called `Ternary Operator` and is a short hand for a `Conditional Operator`
and you can read more about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Now I understand what it does :)